# using Attached Commands to fire a double click event for listview - MVVM

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm, attached-properties

im using Attached command to fire a double click event for an item in `Listview`, ive used the method written in marlon grechs blog - (AttachedCommandBehavior V2 aka ACB), since im using MVVM!

ive used it in a small test example and it works fine, the problem is though, when ive integrated it into the application, i had an exception/error every time the page opened, where the attached property is used.

the exception says:

```
Invalid Operation Exception - Could not resolve event name 
{Void BindEvent(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.String)}
```

and it points to the Eventhandler definition

```
    EventHandler = EventHandlerGenerator.CreateDelegate(
        Event.EventHandlerType, typeof(CommandBehaviorBinding).GetMethod("Execute", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance), this);
```

what is exatly the problem? more importantly, what can i do to resolve it in a MVVM-friendly way? thanx in advance!

```
  <ListView Name="TestListe1" ItemsSource="{Binding TestCollection, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="68,22,620,8" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" FontSize="12">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridView.Columns>
                            <GridViewColumn Width="{Binding TmpWdth,ElementName=ThisPage}" >
                                        <GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate    >
                                        <TextBlock Text="ST1" Margin="10,0,10,1" >              
                                        </TextBlock>
                                       </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                             <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type local:TestListItem}" >
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Element_1, Mode=OneWay}" >
                                            <TextBlock.InputBindings>
                                                 <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding  Openusercontrolcommand}"/>
                                            </TextBlock.InputBindings>
                                        </TextBlock>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Width="Auto">
                                <GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TestListItem}" >
                                        <TextBlock Text="T2" Margin="10,0,10,0" >
                                       </TextBlock>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Element_2, Mode=OneWay}"  >
                                    <TextBlock.InputBindings>
                                        <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding MyDoubleClickCommand}"/>
                                    </TextBlock.InputBindings>
                                    </TextBlock>                                   
                                   </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn>
```

Answer (score 2):

if you just want to handle the double click you could use [UIElement.InputBindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.uielement.inputbindings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ListView.InputBindings>
            <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding MyListViewCommand}"/>
        </ListView.InputBindings>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Item}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}">
                    <TextBlock.InputBindings>
                        <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding MyItemCommand}"/>
                    </TextBlock.InputBindings>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>            
    </ListView>
```

Comment: thank you for ur answer, but is this solution MVVM-combatible? ive edited the description above!

Comment: sure since your VM is now able to handle the DoubleClick, your code behind is free from VM Logic and your VM doesn't get any Visual element.

Comment: its working just for the listview, which means when i click inside the listview but not on the elements! for the textblock its not working, can u please tell which element is defined as "local:Item" ?   thanks in advance

Comment: my ItemsSource is a ObservableCollection<Item> which should be an ViewModel in this case but it depends on your need if the doubleclick on the ListView does what you want, you doesn't need the other stuff but if you also need to fire if the user hits an ListViewItem you had to add command in this item as well

Comment: was genau funktioniert nicht? ich weiss jetzt nicht ob dir das bewusst ist aber es sind 2 verschiedene Klasse das eine welches die `Items` und den `MyListViewCommand` beinhaltet und die Klasse welche deine ListboxItems representiert welche in meinem bsp `Text` und den `MyItemCommand` beinhaltet der rest hängt von der Logik ab welche du anbindest editier mal deine Frage mit deinem aktuellen Code vielleicht sehe ich den Fehler

Comment: mir ist bewusst, da es bei dir um zwei unterschiedliche Klassen handelt
 bei mir tritt keine Fehlermeldung (bezüglich des Text-Commands) auf, passiert jedoch nichts!
den Kode aktualisiere ich oben